# Robolectric - Is there something in Robolectric similar to espresso's typeText?

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, robolectric

In the Robolectric's website (http://robolectric.org/), the product is sold as an alternative without emulator (not instrumented) testing solution enabling full access to Android classes.

So I would like to know, if like espresso, there is something like the `typeText(string)` in Robolectric.

This is because I have associated an `OnKeyListener` to an `EditText` which is not being called if I use `EditText.setText(string)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dispatchKeyEvent`

```
editText.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H))
editText.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I))
assertEquals("hi", editText.text.toString())
```

It is possible to create extension fun that typing any input text:

```
fun EditText.typeText(text: String) {
    val charMap = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD)
    val events: Array<KeyEvent> = charMap.getEvents(text.toCharArray())
    for (e in events) {
        this.dispatchKeyEvent(e)
    }
}
```

If you want to submit `Enter` for `OnKeyListener` it would be enought:

```
editText.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
```

But if you listen for `onEditorAction(v: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean` it is not enough. I found that only this approach could work:

```
fun EditText.performEditorActionDone() {
    this.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
}

fun EditText.performEditorAction(editorAction: Int) {
    this.onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo())
        .performEditorAction(editorAction)
}
```

So unit test could look like this example:

```
@Test
fun `input name, enter - name is saved`() {
    val p: ExamplePresenter = get(...)

    launchFragmentInContainer<ExampleFragment>().let { scenario ->
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
            .onFragment { fragment ->
                fragment.requireView().findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_field).let {
                    it.performClick()
                    it.selectAll()
                    it.typeText("hi")
                    assertEquals("hi", it.text.toString())
                    it.performEditorActionDone()
                    assertEquals("hi", p.state.name)
                }
            }
    }
}
```